# includeProperties in Json struts2 plugin not working

Tags: json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I am using `struts2-json-plugin-2.2.3.jar`. and trying to serialize `filterList` property of class like this:

`struts.xml` code

```
<action name="jsonUserFilterListAction"  class="com.my.fitnessb.actions.UserArticlesAction" method="filterList">
        <result  name="success" type="json">
            <param name="includeProperties">filterList</param>
        </result>
 </action>
```

Action class

```
public class UserArticlesAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, ServletRequestAware {

  private List<FilterType> filterList;
  HttpServletRequest request;

  public String filterList() {
    filterList = new ArrayList<FilterType>();
    filterList.add(new FilterType(10, "Latest Articles"));
    filterList.add(new FilterType(1, "Trending Articles"));
    filterList.add(new FilterType(2, "Top Rated Articles"));
    filterList.add(new FilterType(3, "Most Viewd Atricles"));
    filterList.add(new FilterType(4, "All Atricles"));
    return SUCCESS;
  }
  //setter & getter of filterList
}
```

but I'm not able to get this  property of FilterType class.

Comment: can you get the value if the param `includeProperties` is not used?

Comment: I am getting  seralize all attributes in the action class if the param includeProperties is not used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the fields in your `FilterType` are named `id` and `desc`

Try

```
<param name="includeProperties">
filterList\[\d+\]\.id,
filterList\[\d+\]\.desc
</param>
```

Comment: No problem, although it works I do think it's cumbersome to list out every properties...:/

Answer (score 3):

Struts2-json plugin will seralize your all action attributes in the action class.

Its a problem that I had faced using struts2-json-plugin. Even though the  [plugin-doc](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html) show a working examples for `includeProperties` parameter, it never worked for me and never did after so many trials and googling. So i had to use `excludeProperties` to remove non-required contents from being serialized, instead of specifying what I want to serialize.

Comment: ohh... is it so? This is very bad i think, so i have to use  excludeProperties to remove non-required contents from being serialized, okay thanx...i will check it and get back to you if it will work.Thank you again...buddy

Comment: i tried with json plugin 2.3.8, includeproperties works just fine. if it doesn't works in your project you can trace the source code of json plugin( org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter) it's quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

In case prefer the annotation flavor

```
@ParentPackage("json-default")
@Namespace("/")
@ResultPath(value = "/")
@Results({  @Result(name="firstDir",type="json"
,params = {"includeProperties","fileList\\[\\d+\\]"}
) })

fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File img : folder.listFiles()) {
            fileList.add(img.getName());
        }
return "firstDir"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
<param name="includeProperties">
    filterList.*
</param>
```